# ECW format is not showing in Raster Data Sources in my Geoserver 2.23.2?

Tags: mapping, gis, raster, gdal, geoserver

ECW format is not showing in Raster Data Sources in my Geoserver 2.23.2.I have downloaded and unzipped the "geoserver-2.23.2-gdal-plugin.zip" and pasted that gdal.jar file in 'WEB-INF/lib' location.But still  its not working after restarting geoserver.

Comment: is your gdal version built with ECW and do you have an ECW server licence?

Comment: @IanTurton I have downloaded gdal .jar files from the Geoserver website and I don't have a license. Can you please guide me on how to view the ECW format?

Comment: Well you need an install of gdal built with the ECW plugin. Then you need to buy a licence if you intend to serve ECW images, so I would convert them to geotiffs.

Comment: I already have ECW images Files and I only want to view them in a GeoServer in layer preview. How can I buy the license and install gdal built with the ECW plugin? can you please provide me the links, because, on the Hexagon website, I am not able to find the links. I understand that my questions may be of a basic nature, as I am new to this particular field. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check my repo for ECW support:

- i used original Docker Image docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.25.x,
- and built GDAL 3.8.3 with ECW SDK 5.5.4

https://github.com/cetindogu/geoserver-with-ecw